# Corda - Avoid issuing duplicated states

Tags: java, corda

I am pretty new to Corda, so I might have missed something.
What would be the best way to avoid a party(or different parties) issuing duplicated states?
For example, I want to block issuing an IOU with a seller, buyer,
date and value that was previously issued.

Comment: Your question touches multiple aspects (UTXO, hash, double spending, fungible/non-fungible..). Can you define what you mean by "duplicated state"?

Comment: i am not talking about double spend, i.e. it's not about referencing twice the same input state. but about not allowing a flow(with 0 input state) to issue/create a state as an output if there is already a state in the system with the same properties values.(you shouldn't be able to run the same flow twice) maybe has can work in this case? can you explain more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Corda, states are distributed on a need to know basis; meaning if a party is a `participant` in the state, it will store that state in its vault.
- With that in mind, you can only insure that a certain state is not duplicated on an "issuer" level.
- So let's say in your IOU it's always the `lender` that issues new IOUs; so your flow (which is initiated by the `lender`) should first query the vault of the `lender` to see if there is a matching IOU and throw an exception if it does, otherwise issue the new IOU.
- So if you had an IOU with `lender = PartyA` and `borrower = PartyB`; there's no way for PartyC to know that the mentioned IOU exists (because it's not a `participant` in that state).
- Which isn't a problem, because you should write your flow in a way that the initiator of the flow becomes the `lender` of the IOU; and this way you have things locked down.
- Every `lender` checks their vault before issuing an IOU for similar ones.